# Call name of function having multiple parameters from a python dictionary to another function

Tags: python

I am trying to call function from python dictionary one by one into another function

```
feature={
1:[perm_entropy, 3, True],
2:[svd_entropy, 3, 1, True],
3:[petrosian_fd],
4:[katz_fd],
5:[higuchi_fd],
6:[hjorth_mobility],
7:[hjorth_complexity]}
```

i am trying to call above function as follows

```
sub_25=[]
for i in feature.values():
    sub_25.append(sub25.groupby('trial')[col1].agg(i))
```

Except the first 2 function, all other functions are working correctly. I thinks it is because of extra parameters they have.
These two function work well, if they are called separately as follow

```
sub_25.append(sub25.groupby('trial')[col1].agg(perm_entropy, 3, True))
```

How can i deal these two functions?
[EEG data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS2QR.png)

Comment: `sub25` and `col1` are not defined in your example. Please make a [mcve]. The data is irrelevant btw.

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a list into multiple function arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), the pandas `agg` method accepts a function as the first argument, optional axis second, and then positional arguments which will be passed to the function specified.

To do this in your for loop, you should use `*` to unpack `i` since `i` is a list of the arguments you need to pass to `agg`.

```py
sub_25=[]
for i in feature.values():
    sub_25.append(sub25.groupby('trial')[col1].agg(*i))
```

For example, imagine `i = [perm_entropy, 3, True]`, then `sub_25.append(sub25.groupby('trial')[col1].agg(*i))` is equivalent to `sub_25.append(sub25.groupby('trial')[col1].agg(perm_entropy, 3, True))` which is what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is partially applied function for your use-case. Python's **functools** package can take care of this. You can change your code as per the following example:

```
from functools import partial

def addthree(a,b,c): 
    return a+b+c

partial_sum = partial(addthree,1,2)

fdict = {1: partial_sum}

fdict[1](4) // this returns 7 on the console
```

Similarly you can write `perm_entropy` with its required arguments and pass
your values later

```
new_perm_entropy = partial(perm_entropy,3,True)
feature = {1: new_perm_entropy,..}
feature[1](your_args_here)
```

You can read up on Partially Applied Functions for further clarifications.